# Name of tables exporting from R to excel

Tags: r, excel, export

I have different lists of dataframes that I bind together before exporting in excel with this code:

```
l_listOfDF <- mget(ls(pattern="listofdf"))
```

The export works fine using:

```
mywb <- createWorkbook()

for (sheetName in names(listofdfs)){
  addWorksheet(mywb , sheetName )
}

# get all lists of tables in a single list
l_listOfDF <- mget(ls(pattern="listofdf"))

# initiate the index of the row where you will want to start writing (one per sheet)
startR <- rep(1, length(listofdfs)) ; names(startR) <- names(listofdfs)

# loop over the lists of tables using index and then over the elements / sheets using their names
for(N_myListOfDF in seq(l_listOfDF)){
  
  for(pageName in names(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]])){
    
    label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", pageName, " users between 2010-2019")
    
    # write the name/number of your table in the correct sheet, at the correct row
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName], label_2)
    
    # write your data in the correct sheet at the correct row (the one after the name)
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName]+1, l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]])
    
    # update the row number (the + 3 is to leave space for name of table, headers and blank row
    startR[pageName] <- startR[pageName]+nrow(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]]) + 3
  }
}
```

but I can't assign to each table I'm exporting the right title.

In the label:

```
label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", pageName, " users between 2010-2019")
```

I'd like to add something like:

```
x <- c("","","females","males")
```

and obtain:

```
label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", x, pageName, " users between 2010-2019")
```

In order to have, for the first table of each excel sheet, the follow title:

Table 1. Number of (pageName) users between 2010-2019

For the second table of each excel sheet:

Table 2. Number of (pageName) users between 2010-2019

The third:

Table 3. Number of ***females*** (pageName) users between 2010-2019

The forth:

Table 4. Number of ***males*** (pageName) users between 2010-2019

But just adding the vector x in label_2 doesn't work properly.
I got tables multiplied in each sheet.

Any helpful idea? Thanks!

Here a reproducible example:

```
listofdfs <- list(data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011),"b"=c(35,30,20)), data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "b"=c(6,21,40)), data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(13,30,5), "b"=c(40,18,25)), data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(8,36,7), "b"=c(32,9,17))  )

listofdfs_2 <- list(data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011),"b"=c(14,36,8)), data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "b"=c(36,27,9)), data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(9,15,58), "b"=c(7,11,20)), data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(48,3,67), "b"=c(2,28,37))  )

mywb <- createWorkbook()

for (sheetName in names(listofdfs)){
  addWorksheet(mywb , sheetName )
}

# get all lists of tables in a single list
l_listOfDF <- mget(ls(pattern="listofdf"))

# initiate the index of the row where you will want to start writing (one per sheet)
startR <- rep(1, length(listofdfs)) ; names(startR) <- names(listofdfs)

# loop over the lists of tables using index and then over the elements / sheets using their names
for(N_myListOfDF in seq(l_listOfDF)){

  for(pageName in names(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]])){

    label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", c("","","females","males"), pageName, " users between 2010-2019")

    # write the name/number of your table in the correct sheet, at the correct row
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName], label_2)

    # write your data in the correct sheet at the correct row (the one after the name)
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName]+1, l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]])

    # update the row number (the + 3 is to leave space for name of table, headers and blank row
    startR[pageName] <- startR[pageName]+nrow(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]]) + 3
  }
}

# save your workbook in a file
saveWorkbook(mywb , "diroutput\\pippo.xlsx")
```

Comment: Any idea? Would it be better with a reproducible example?

Comment: Yes, a reproducible example might be helpful here.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to edit my question and add an example!

Comment: Done it! Is it better now?

Comment: Does the answer below give you what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a simple vector with your labels and define elsewhere, something like:

```
label_vec <- c("","","females","males")
```

Then, to get your title labels, use an index from `N_myListOfDF` to get the correct text label:

```
label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", label_vec[N_myListOfDF], " ", pageName, " users between 2010-2019")
```

The example above only has two tables and the list of data frames didn't have names, so I made some minor modifications to get a reproducible example (below). Also, there were only 2 tables in the example, so I used test1 and test2 instead of empty strings to test it.

**Reproducible example**:

```
library(openxlsx)

listofdfs <- list(
  "One" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011),"b"=c(35,30,20)), 
  "Two" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "b"=c(6,21,40)), 
  "Three" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(13,30,5), "b"=c(40,18,25)), 
  "Four" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(8,36,7), "b"=c(32,9,17))  
)

listofdfs_2 <- list(
  "One" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011),"b"=c(14,36,8)), 
  "Two" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "b"=c(36,27,9)), 
  "Three" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(9,15,58), "b"=c(7,11,20)), 
  "Four" = data.frame("y"=c(2009,2010,2011), "a"=c(48,3,67), "b"=c(2,28,37))  
)

mywb <- createWorkbook()

for (sheetName in names(listofdfs)){
  addWorksheet(mywb , sheetName )
}

# get all lists of tables in a single list
l_listOfDF <- mget(ls(pattern="listofdf"))

# initiate the index of the row where you will want to start writing (one per sheet)
startR <- rep(1, length(listofdfs))
names(startR) <- names(listofdfs)

# create vector of labels to insert into table titles
label_vec <- c("test1","test2","females","males")

# loop over the lists of tables using index and then over the elements / sheets using their names
for(N_myListOfDF in seq(l_listOfDF)){
  
  for(pageName in names(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]])){
    
    #label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", c("","","females","males"), pageName, " users between 2010-2019")
    label_2 <- paste0("Table ", N_myListOfDF, ". Number of ", label_vec[N_myListOfDF], " ", pageName, " users between 2010-2019")
    
    # write the name/number of your table in the correct sheet, at the correct row
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName], label_2)
    
    # write your data in the correct sheet at the correct row (the one after the name)
    writeData(mywb, sheet=pageName, startRow=startR[pageName]+1, l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]])
    
    # update the row number (the + 3 is to leave space for name of table, headers and blank row
    startR[pageName] <- startR[pageName]+nrow(l_listOfDF[[N_myListOfDF]][[pageName]]) + 3
  }
}

# save your workbook in a file
saveWorkbook(mywb , "pippo.xlsx", overwrite = T)
```